# Sync Tango with external sensors

Tags: clock, google-project-tango

What is the preferred method to synchronize Tango timestamps with external sensor data?  Are there hardware clkin/clkout signals available somewhere on the device?
Of course we could just apply a constant value adjustment, but that would not correct for clock jitter and drift as clock synch would.  Those could be a significant source of error.

In my case, I want to physically attach a directional antenna array to Tango; capture the RF data with synchronized Software Defined Radios(SDR) HackRFs http://greatscottgadgets.com; and correlate the RF samples with the pose and camera data.  This will allow me to walk around and rapidly locate multiple intermittent spurious RF transmissions within a 20MHZ bandwidth by overlaying their calculated position onto the map.  True example: I am control systems advisor at a FIRST Robotics Competition. Large potentially dangerous robots are controlled by high school kids using WiFi signals, so it is important that we eliminate threats to the integrity of the control signals.  With this, I could simultaneously see: exactly which team in the pits has their printer WiFi accidentally turned on; exactly who in the stands is actively trying to hack the Field Management System signals from their cell phone; track the movement of robots on the field for later simulation of the match, as the robots already have CAD models; see that a broadcast camera feed has just been switched on; and locate where someone lost a hot radio mic.

Other elements that might require the same synchronization would be overlaying correlated sonar sensor data; infrared heat camera data, solar impact data, realtime wind speed and direction vector field, realtime quadcopter swarm locations, pyro sensors to detect flames, O2 and CO sensors to locate breathable pockets of air within a burning building for firemen, basically any situation requiring real time situational awareness.
edit+
Synchronization would also allow multiple Tango devices to be connected achieving full spherical capture.  Besides sharing the processing load and speeding environment capture, I'm not sure at this point what that would be useful for, but there must be something.